# Extract alphanumeric and number + special char from text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract out a mix of alphanumeric and numbers from a text. Both type of words may have special characters in them like '-'. Example of the text is below.

`text = 'This item is A12345, with serial no. 123 456 789 or 123456789, ref no. 876-543, code ABC-D-123.'`

I have come out with this:
`re.findall('(\w*\d+)', text)`.

But it returns: `['A12345', '123', '456', '789', '123456789', '876', '543', '123']`

The expected output is:`['A12345', '123 456 789', '123456789', '876-543', 'ABC-D-123']`

Also the item `A12345` can have different variations like `12A345` or `12345A`. This is similar to the ref no. where `'ABC-D-123'` can also be `'ABC-FF-123-456'`, `'FF-123-456-AB'`, etc.

edit: removed ** for bolding output in code to avoid confusion

edit2: amended SKU to serial

Comment: I don't "get" the rules here.  Why is `SKU` not a match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i'm intending to keep them as 1 string. Thinking of using sub instead of findall where I can split them later, but a sub [a-zA-Z] would remove the A in A12345 and ABCD in ABC-D-123. Hope this clarifies

Comment: Doesn't clarify at all.  You never gave us the rules for why `SKU` would not be a match, given that you would expect something similar like `ABC` to match.

Comment: SKU is a word in the text. I'm extracting the item, serial and ref no. Amended SKU to serial to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recent edit, the following regex pattern seems to work:

```
\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:[ -][A-Z0-9]+)*\b
```

This just says to match collections of words with capitals or digits, separated by space or hyphen, should a given match have more than one word.

Full script:

```
text = 'This item is A12345, with serial no. 123 456 789 or 123456789, ref no. 876-543, code ABC-D-123.'
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:[ -][A-Z0-9]+)*\b', text)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['A12345', '123 456 789', '123456789', '876-543', 'ABC-D-123']
```